# increase textarea size according to the size of the text in the angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Currently the following code is being used to resize the textarea

```
function autoResize(el){
  while (el.scrollHeight > el.offsetHeight){
    el.rows += 1;
  }
}
```

but it only resizes when I hover over the textarea

```
<textarea onmousemove="autoResize(this)"></textarea>
```

I would like to make it resize automatically when I open the screen that has the textarea. I already tried switching to onload but without success

Comment: add autoResize()  to ngOnInit() method of component and  you can call it on keyup event too.

Comment: how would i do it? 
would i have to put the autoResize() function in ngOninit()?

Answer (score 0):

```
export class TextAreaComponent extends OnInit { 
 @ViewChild('textarea', { read: ElementRef,static:true }) textarea: ElementRef; 
  @Input() value:string;
  rowCount: number;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._autoResize(this.textarea.nativeElement);
  }

  onKeyup(el) {
    this._autoResize(el);
  }
  private _autoResize(el) {
   while (el.scrollHeight > el.offsetHeight){
     el.rows += 1;
   }
  }  
}
```

and template of textarea component might be look like this

```
<textarea
  #textarea
  [value]="!value ? '' : value"
  (keyup)="onKeyup(textarea)"
></textarea>
```

I have created some sample code for you.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kxszjh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts